# Take two a list of strings as input in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to take a list of strings as input using List comprehensions. Here is what I've tried and it gives me errors.

```
m,n = raw_input().strip().split()
 matrix = [ [str(in) for in in raw_input().strip()] for i in xrange(n)]
 print matrix
```

It is supposed to receive a list of strings (sth like a 2d m x n array in C). However its giving me error as `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: Don't use `in` as a variable name, as you've done in your second list comprehension. Refer to my answer below :3

Comment: Note that in all cases `string.strip().split()` will give the same results as `string.split()`

Comment: work with an IDE like PyDev, you will easily see errors like this one.

Comment: @Elazar Good point, especially with the syntax highlighting and all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` is a keyword. You're using it here thinking it's a variable.:

```
matrix = [[str(in) for in in raw_input().strip()] for i in xrange(n)]
```

It's a `SyntaxError` because python thinks you're saying `in` twice, when you're intending to do something different. So change `in` to another name.

Comment: Reminds me of cobol's `if if = then then then = else else else = if`